# Radio Group + Swipe Navigation + Button Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, radio-button

I have researched and tried various algorithms and ritual dances but to no avail.  I need a three page layout that will be implemented through android swipe.  I can get that set up just fine.  The issue I am having is on my first layout I have a radio group, edit text field and a button.  To test that the radio buttons are being selected properly I have the OnCheckedChangeListener edit the id of the radio button to the hint field of the edit text box. My first implementation here.

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
    {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;   

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) 
    {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) 
    {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given        page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.

        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) 
    {
        switch (position) 
        {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_section1);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_section2);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_section3);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment 
{
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    RadioGroup group1;
    RadioButton radio1, radio2, radio3;
    EditText editText1;

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        // Create a new TextView and set its text to the fragment's section
        // number argument value.

        int position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

         int resId = 0;
            switch (position) 
            {
                case 1:
                    resId = R.layout.layout1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    resId = R.layout.layout2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    resId = R.layout.layout3;
                    break;
            }

    View view = inflater.inflate(resId, container, false);


    if (position == 1)
    {
    group1 = (RadioGroup)
            findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        radio1 = (RadioButton)
            group1.findViewById(group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        radio2 = (RadioButton)
            group1.findViewById(group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        radio3 = (RadioButton)
            group1.findViewById(group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

        editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);


        group1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {

            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
            {
                switch (checkedId)
                {
                    case R.id.radio1:
                        editText1.setHint("Layout1 selected");
                        break;

                    case R.id.radio2:
                        editText1.setHint("Layout2 selected");
                        break;

                    case R.id.radio3:
                        editText1.setHint("Layout3 selected");
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
    }
    return view;
    }


        }
        }
```

will implement the layouts just fine but fails when adding the last if statement (if (position == 1)

However, my next implementation works but after I swipe to layout3, layout1 doesn't reinstantiate my argument as it did when it first loads up
Here is the code snippet

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Parcelable;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
   myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    RadioGroup group1;
    RadioButton radio1, radio2, radio3;
    EditText editText1;

    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_section1);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_section2);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_section3);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       int resId = 0;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resId = R.layout.layout1;
            break;
        case 1:
            resId = R.layout.layout2;
            break;
        case 2:
            resId = R.layout.layout3;
            break;
        }

        String a = Integer.toString(position);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       if (position == 1){
                group1 = (RadioGroup)
                    findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
            radio1 = (RadioButton)
                    group1.findViewById(group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            radio2 = (RadioButton)
                    group1.findViewById(group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
            radio3 = (RadioButton)
                    group1.findViewById(group1.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

            editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            group1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() 
              {

                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
                {
                    switch (checkedId)
                    {
                        case R.id.radio1:
                            editText1.setHint("radio1");
                            break;

                        case R.id.radio2:
                            editText1.setHint("radio2");
                            break;

                        case R.id.radio3:
                            editText1.setHint("radio3");
                            break;
                    }

                } 
              });
        }

        View view = inflater.inflate(resId, null);

        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) 
    {

        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) 
    {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);

    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() 
    {
        return null;
    }
    } 
        }
```

Here is my main layout and layout 1

main.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<!--
This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
titles for adjacent pages.
-->

<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
    android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

layout1.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="radio1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="radio2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="radio3" />
</RadioGroup>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```